# How do you change the thickness of all the edges in a graph in gephi?

Tags: graph, gephi

I'm trying to visualise a graph with about 30 nodes and 100 edges, however the edges in gephi are too thin and I'm unable to find a way to increase their thickness. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the edge thickness slider:

[image]